# Provider Error when using dynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to load a component inside a DIV on my Site. When I run this Code:

```
renderPopoverContent(event: Termine.FullCalendarEvent) {
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        { provide: 'termin', useValue: event }            
    ]);
    this._dynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot(PopoverComponent, '#popover_' + event.id, injector);
}
```

I get this error to Console

> No provider for ViewUtils!

I am using the latest Angular2 Version (2.0.0-rc.3)

Comment: For an example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: But how can I insert the new component inside a DOM-Element by ID? (#popover_....)

Comment: As far as I know you can't. Angular2 supports template variables and directives to query for targets.

Comment: is it possible to create a ViewElement from a DOM-Element dynamicaly?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: in the so-link you posted, you have these two lines: 
@ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
and later...
this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)

what I need is something like:
this.target = "create ViewChild by selector '#popover_...'"

Comment: As mentioned above, I don't think there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DynamicComponentLoader` is **deprecated**

Use `ComponentResolver` and `ViewContainerRef` directly.